# MYSQL: Select the highest ID from two colums and sort

Tags: mysql, select, join, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT
    u.uid, 
    u.name, 
    u.description, 
    u.url, 
    u.picurl, 
    u.mapurl, 
    MAX(p.pid) AS MaxPriceID,
    p.price,
    p.uid,
    MAX(r.rid) AS MaxRatingID,
    r.rating,
    r.uid
FROM
    utested u
        JOIN price p
            ON u.uid=p.uid
        JOIN rating r
            ON u.uid=r.rid
GROUP BY u.uid, u.name
```

This query displays what I need but it does not display the correct values.

I want to display the HIGHEST PID and RID
I get the highest PID and RID but not the highest price and rating.

There are 3 tables.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: do you need all other details correspoding to highest pid, rid or you want all details from utested , along with max values as separate columns?

Comment: may be in your tables highest PID does not correspond to highest rating and price ?

Comment: You need to get highest pid and rid in one query then get coresponding price and rating by join or subquery.

Comment: Are you trying to get 2 records? One with the highest price and one with the highest rating? Where do you refer to the "highest price" or "highest rating" (and not the pid/rid)?

Comment: Radar: I need the highest price for the latest PID and all details from utested. And i need the latest price in its own column. i dont need the pid column really.

And the RID i want the average rating. Not the highest rid.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at in the comments, you should use a subquery to get the highest ratings, and then use that in your join statement in this case.

Try changing it to this:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.name, u.description, u.url
   u.picurl, u.mapurl, p.price, p.uid, r.rating, r.uid
FROM utested u
JOIN price p ON u.uid = p.uid AND p.uid = (SELECT MAX(pid) FROM price)
JOIN rating r ON u.uid = r.rid AND r.rid = (SELECT MAX(rid) FROM rating);
```

I can't test without any sample data, but I'm hoping this will do what you want or can be tweaked closely to what you want.

Comment: it didnt work. but se my other answer that explains a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

@McAdam331: Thank you for pointing me but it didnt work, but it helped me rewriting the query.

I have created a sqlfiddle with my dataset. And i have found another "problem". I need the rating to be average. Using the AVG(rating) to get a score that is like 4.3 (1 decimal)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93b771/1